# Is it possible to give a single variable multiple integer values to be checked for in an 'if statement'

Tags: java, if-statement, int

I am confused on how I receive an "Illegal start of expression... not a statement" error from NetBeans. I'm coding in Java and am still quite new to it.

Long story short, I want to know if there's a way to make a single variable be checked for multiple integer values (not sure if I worded that correctly.) Here is my code, the error it returns was mentioned in first paragraph:

```
 if (month == 1) && (month == 3) && (month == 5) && (month == 7) && (month == 8) && (month == 10) && (month == 12)
```

It's my first time using the sight so I apologize if the format wasn't correct.

Comment: Yes. Wrap everything after the `if` between an additional pair of parentheses. You may want to check your logic though. One variable can have only one value at a time...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`if (month == 1 && month == 3 && month == 5 && month == 7 && month == 8 && month == 10 && month == 12) {}`

But why do you use `&&` here? The expression is always `false`. Shouldn't you use `||`?

Comment: I’ll be sure to try this. Thank you, I was thinking of something like this but didn’t know how to write it. Thanks

Comment: @VuyoJantjies You are very welcome. Please mark this as the answer if you think it has helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

1. A syntactically correct java if statement expects one pair of brackets `if (...)`, but you wrote many pairs `if (...)(...)...`. That's where the syntax error comes from.
2. AND (&&) is the wrong logical operator. OR (||) would be the correct operator.

Possible solutions:

```
if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12)

if ((month == 1) || (month == 3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7) || (month == 8) || (month == 10) || (month == 12))
```

Alternatively use a switch case statement:

```
switch (month) {
    case 1:  // do something ...;
             break;
    case 3:  // do something ...;
             break;
    case 5:  // do something ...;
             break;
    case 7:  // do something ...;
             break;
    case 8:  // do something ...;
             break;
    case 10: // do something ...;
             break;
    case 12: // do something ...;
             break;
    default: // month is not in one if the given values;
             break;
}
```

Or you could use a loop:

```
int[] values = {1,3,5,7,8,10,12};
for (int i : values) {
    if (month == i) {
        // do something ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but you have a syntax error, you need to wrap your condition into parantheses:

```
if ((month == 1) && (month == 3) && (month == 5) && (month == 7) && (month == 8) && (month == 10) && (month == 12)) {
    //Your code
}
```

But this is logically problematic, since this will never be true. You most probably wanted to check if your variable has any of the month values specified:

```
if ((month == 1) || (month == 3) || (month == 5) || (month == 7) || (month == 8) || (month == 10) || (month == 12)) {
    //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you say checked for multiple integer values Im going to assume you mean that you want to see if the month is any of the following values.

So you need to change your parenthisys up a little.

```
if ((month == 1) && (month == 3) && (month == 5) && (month == 7) && (month == 8) && (month == 10) && (month == 12))
```

Having that first if(month== 1) ends the if statement and so anything else is unexpected.

Furthermore I think you want the OR operator || rather than the and && since its unlikely that month will be all of those values at once.

Answer (score 0):

use

`if ((month == 1) && (month == 3) && (month == 5) && (month == 7) && (month == 8) && (month == 10) && (month == 12))`

If you are talking about real month scenario then month can only be `true` once and so the compound `&&` statement will always be `false`. I think you intended to use `||`.

suppose

```
 month = 3;
```

then

```
if ((3== 1) && (3== 3) && (3== 5) && (3== 7) && (3== 8) && (3== 10) && (3== 12))
```

will return `false` even when it is true once.

but in `||` case

```
if ((3== 1) || (3== 3) || (3== 5) || (3== 7) || (3== 8) || (3== 10) || (3== 12))
```

then it will return `true`

Comment: That answer contains the same content as the one by @6324. At least provide additional information, explain the code.

Answer (score 0):

General syntax for an `if` condition

```
if (condition) {
  // stuff
}
```

The key here is the condition is surrounded by parentheses. Your condition might be composed of different expressions:

```
if (month == 1) { // month equals 1
  // stuff
}

if (month == 1 || month == 2) { // month equals either 1 or 2.
  // stuff
}
```

It is not necessary to surround every expression with parentheses; it is usually used for order of operations when you have multiple operators involved for example when your condition includes both `&&` and `||` and you don't want to let Java figure out how to group them together.